# Using metal roofing for ceiling

Tags: ceiling, metal

My outside porch has a plywood ceiling.  Can I put metal directly over the plywood?  I live in the southeast.

Comment: Tin/metal ceilings are a thing.  The only thing is they usually don't leak/show signs of leaks so it might be too long before you notice a roof leak.  Rotten roof members.

Comment: Might want to look/search tin ceilings if you want a design for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a perfectly viable option for the underside of a porch roof. I've also seen it done for a garage ceiling.